# Job scheduler with target list

Tags: linux, security, scheduler

I want to have a scheduler that can run a command on a list of targets using a cluster of nodes.

So, for example I want to run Nmap on a list of IP's. These IP's can be in a CSV, JSON, database etc. that's not a problem. I want the scheduler to take one IP from the list and run "Nmap IP" on one of the nodes then take the next IP from the list and run this on the next node.

This seems like something a job scheduler would have but for some reason i cannot find any scheduler that does this.

Comment: What did you try? Could you add the attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Write a script or develop an application to do what you want and add a cron job to execute it whenever you want it to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Opta planner https://www.optaplanner.org/ for mapping run time load ip. It is an opensource software but needs a basic core of java.